# How to use $.dialog.confirm() with JQuery's ZLDialog popup dialog handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

The following page shows all the documentation.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Tiny-Feature-rich-jQuery-Dialog-Popup-Plugin-ZLDialog.html

I have no trouble getting simple (OK) dialogs to work. However, there is no example of a Yes/No dialog and all my attempts to get it work have failed.

Comment: Can you post your failed attempts please? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you James. The author sent me a piece of code and I turned it into English and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

As James mentioned in the comment under your post, it would be helpful to have an example of your failed attempt. That said, here is a fiddle showing a basic example with a callback on confirm:

http://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/avcLrtzd/

```
$("#demo-dialog-callback").click(function() {
  $.dialog({
    content: "Dialog with callback",
    hideX: true,
    drag: false,
    lock: false,
    closeBack: function() {
      $.dialog.message({
        content: "Callback content"
      });
    },
    buttons: [{
      text: "Click me"
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you iamjpg. I tried out your example and it works fine.

Above is something based on what the author showed me

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDialog = $.dialog.confirm({
    content: "Do you want to continue?"}, 
        function () {
    $.dialog.message({
        content: "Yes",
                timeout:1000
    });

    myDialog();

}, function () { 
    $.dialog.message({
        content: "No",
                timeout:1000
    }); 
        myDialog();
});
```